# Extracting percentage on a statement in a cell Excel

Tags: excel

I am trying to create a formula that will extract the percentage on a statement. Cells may look like this:

```
ABCD - ABCD RANDOM - 77% - MM/DD/YY EXPENSES DEC. 20 QTR

WXYZ - WXYZ RANDOM2 - 58.8% - MM/DD/YY EXPENSES DEC. 21 QTR
```

Data that should be extracted should look like this:

```
77%

58.8%
```

Can anyone please suggest?

Comment: This is about getting a substring from text. It's not *extracting a percentage*. You should search for *substring text excel*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `FILTERXML()` formula. You have to format resulting cells as `Percentage` otherwise you will get calculated value like `.77`.

```
=FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(A1," ","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s[contains(., '%')]")
```

If you are not interested to change cells format to `Percentage` then use `TEXT()` function like-

```
=TEXT(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(A1," ","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s[contains(., '%')]")*100,"@")&"%"
```

[image]